# Register Service workers

Tags: reactjs

I want to work using registerServiceworkers but each time I install react only reportwebvitals.js is installed. So, can anyone guide me to use registerServiceWorkers instead of reportwebvitals.js as I am new to React?

Comment: reportWebVitals and service works are two different thing and using for two different purpose. what are you trying to do ?